# Making vim the default editor in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ubuntu, vim, file-association

While trying to make vim default instead of gedit, I found this could be done two ways:

1. Use `defaults.list` and make `text/plain` (and others) point to `vim.desktop` (what is the format for creating `.desktop` files?)
2. Use `update-alternatives` and change `gnome-text-editor` (right now it has only one alternative, so I guess I have to install one more. How to do that?)

Which is the better way to do it?

Comment: how do you want to launch (g)vim? command line? clicking a icon?

Comment: @akira: If I click a text file, vim should open in a terminal.

Comment: any objections against gvim?

Comment: @akira 1. I don't have it installed, 2. Why not `vim`?

Comment: @N 1.1: coz you have to associate something like 'xterm -e vim ' with the extension you want to use. vim is a terminal application (it has no 'window').

Comment: @akira I tried something and its working. See my answer http://superuser.com/questions/268164/make-vim-default/268170#268170 .

Comment: you can add http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-actions-spec and http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/desktop-entry-spec to your question (as references, the 2nd link is about .desktop entries).

Comment: @akira: The .desktop file spec allows for programs that require a terminal (`Terminal=true`). I have been using vim and mutt myself this way.

Answer (score 4):

There is a command

> select-editor

That is for the user. Globally You can use update-alternatives to set editor to vim

Comment: If your editor isn't on the list, do this first (for geany) `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/geany 10`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have created `vim.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` and modified `defaults.list` (in the same dir) to include

```
text/plain=vim.desktop
```

After that, `sudo update-mime` and its working! (*I am not sure whether this step is require*)

Clicking on a text file opens `vim`, not gvim, in terminal and `:q` closes the terminal too.

<sub>p.s. there are many *.desktop in the mentioned folder, copy the necessary key=values from them and create `vim.desktop`</sub>

Answer (score -2):

When you install the vim packages one of those change the default editor for you.
I think it's the gvim package that fixes your problem.

```
aptitude install vim vim-scripts vim-doc vim-gui-common vim-gnome
```

And the most common way to use vim is that if you start it from X you start gvim, 
and if you are in a terminal you start vim.